# responseType of an XHR is an empty string

Tags: ajax

I just want to retrieve the DOM tree of that [XML](http://satya.kodingen.com/computers.xml) with that [JS snippet](http://pastebin.com/egrYEWwi).

I get "undefined" for a.responseXML and I don't know why, because a.responseText contains it, but as string. I found out the responseType is an empty string and I know responseXML is sensible for type.

What I did wrong?

Comment: What is `WinJS` anyway? I would suspect it being the problem since inspecting response of that XML link produces `Content-Type:  application/xml` as expected.

Comment: WinJS is a namespace, but look at [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx). It's beta and can has bugs, but I wish it isn't one of them.

Comment: well you said it yourself, it can have bugs, so switch to something that is stable :)

Comment: 404 - satya.kodingen.com does not exist.